# Tuleap - Should cross-references go across projects and not enforce tracker name and project permissions?

Tags: cross-reference, tuleap

I am using a project in which a have a tracker named "Epic", so when I type "Epic #123", I get a link to artifact 123.  This works fine.

However, if I type a tracker name that exists in my project (e.g. "Epic") followed by #x, the tool creates a link to artifact #x regardless of the location of the artifact and of its actual type.

Since "Epic" is defined as a tracker in my project, typing "Epic #1" creates a link to artifact #1, which is in another project and is of a different type, here the type is "Feature Requests".

[image: Tuleap screenshot]

Questions:

1. Is this linking across projects normal?
2. Is it ok that the tracker types are different?
3. Should there be checking for type or artifacts and access rights?

Note: I experimented and typing "artifact #1" also returns the same link, which tells me that "artifact" is a generic way of linking without using a tracker name.  Linking to an artifact inside a private project creates the link but does not show the artifact when clicking on the link.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Is this linking across projects normal?

Yes it is

> 2- Is it ok that the tracker types are different?

Yes it is

> 3- Should there be checking for type or artifacts and access rights?

While we could check/limit creation of links only if we detect that the correct pattern is used (ie. that id does belong to corresponding tracker). It's much harder to do it with respect of access rights.

> Note: I experimented and typing "artifact #1" also returns the same
>   link, which tells me that "artifact" is a generic way of linking
>   without using a tracker name. Linking to an artifact inside a private
>   project creates the link but does not show the artifact when clicking
>   on the link.

Yep. artifact #XXX is a generic way to reference any artifact across projects/platofrm